# AngularJS daterange filter

Tags: angularjs, date, date-range

I would like to get a filter in AngularJS that allows me to filter events between a certain date. For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>            
</head>
<body ng-init="data = [{name : 'Hike', date : '23/09/2013'}, {name : 'Museum visit', date : '25/09/2013'}, {name : 'Trip to Paris', date : '01/10/2013'}]">
  <label>Date:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="event.date" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <table>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <tr ng-repeat="event in data | filter:event">
      <td>{{event.date}}</td>
      <td>{{event.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

With this, I can look up a date an see whether there's an event on that date, but I would like to get a daterange. I have look at [this daterange-picker](http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/), but I don't know how to integrate this so that it works with the table.

Comment: Have you defined a controller?

Comment: No, the code you see above is all I have so far.

Comment: I am pretty certain you are using the wrong tool for your needs.  It's just a guess but Angular is really a programmatic+declarative framework, meaning that you are going to need a good amount of javascript to implement almost anything.  If this is true I can suggest some alternatives to angular that might better fit your needs.

Comment: I'm always open to suggestions, but since there exists a daterange picker for AngularJS, there must exist an implementation which isn't too hard either, I would think.

Comment: I would recommend going through the angular tutorial. Step 3 covers this very use case. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03